# About definition of stable solution. $Q_u(\phi) \ge 0$ for all $\phi \in C_c^1(\Omega)$ replaced by "for all $\phi \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I want to ask about a remark about the stable solution of elliptic PDE [Remark 1.1.1](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=lP_LBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=stable%20outside%20a%20compact%20set&source=bl&ots=l6I2A2BHkr&sig=ACfU3U0LaVoD_Vea8jpe6Cyb3CKmBWDDxg&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=stable%20outside%20a%20compact%20set&f=false).

We say $u$ is stable solution of $-\Delta u=f(u) \ \text { in } \Omega$ and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ if it satisfies the following definition. Here $u \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and $f \in C^1(\Omega)$.
$$
Q_u(\varphi):=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla \varphi|^2 d x-\int_{\Omega} f^{\prime}(u) \varphi^2 d x \geq 0, \quad \forall \varphi \in C_c^1(\Omega),
$$
then the remark in the book said **using a standard approximation argument, if $\Omega$ is bounded or merely if $f^{\prime}(u)^{-}$ is bounded in $\Omega$, one can take $\varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ in the above definition.**

I want to ask that the remark said that the two definition is equal when $\Omega$ is bounded or $f^{\prime}(u)^{-}$ is bounded. $Q_u(\varphi) \ge 0$, $\forall \varphi \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ obviously implies $Q_u(\varphi) \ge 0$, $\forall \varphi \in C_c^1(\Omega)$.  The opposite direction should also be correct if we let $\left|f^{\prime}(u)\right|$ is bounded (definition of $W_0^{1,2}$ space), but here they merely let  $f^{\prime}(u)^{-}$to be bounded, I'm not sure about this step.

Comment: The positive part of $f'(u)$ can be handled with Fatou's lemma no matter how $f'(u)^+$ behaves.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't know if I misunderstood, did you mean that for the approximation process, rewrite $\int_{\Omega}|\nabla \varphi_n|^2 d x-\int_{\Omega} f^{\prime}(u) \varphi_n^2 d x \geq 0$ as  $\int_{\Omega}|\nabla \varphi_n|^2 d x+\int_{\Omega} f^{\prime}(u) ^{-}\varphi_n^2 d x \geq \int_{\Omega} f^{\prime}(u) ^{+}\varphi_n^2 d x$, then use the fatou lemma on the RHS, so we only have to let $f^{\prime}(u)^{-}$to be bounded?

Comment: That's what I meant yes!